# Using $/ is not exactly the same as using any other variable in grammar actions

Tags: grammar, raku

In theory, and [according to the documentation](https://docs.perl6.org/language/grammars#Action_objects), you can use any argument for methods in grammar actions.

```
grammar G {
    token TOP { \w+ }
}

class Action-Arg {
    method TOP ($match) { $match.make: ~$match }
}

class Action {
    method TOP ($/) { make ~$/ }
}

class Action-Fails {
    method TOP ($match) { make ~$match }
}

say G.parse( "zipi", actions => Action-Arg );
say G.parse( "zape", actions => Action );
say G.parse( "pantuflo", actions => Action-Fails );
```

However, the two first versions work as expected. But the third one (which would be a direct translation of the second), fails with

```
Cannot bind attributes in a Nil type object
  in method TOP at match-and-match.p6 line 19
  in regex TOP at match-and-match.p6 line 7
  in block <unit> at match-and-match.p6 line 24
```

There's probably some special syntax going on (in the sense of `make` being actually `$/.make`, probably), but I'd just like to clarify if this is according to spec or is a bug.

Comment: A friendly reminder for readers and writers. (This is unrelated to JJ's real question.) In computing there is a distinction between **A)** a *value* that is passed as part of a function *call* and **B)** a *variable* that the value is bound to in the [signature](https://docs.perl6.org/type/Signature) of a function's *definition*. The term most commonly used by programmers for the former is *argument*. For the latter, in several programming language cultures, including P6, the preferred term is *parameter* to avoid confusion. In the above question, JJ meant "parameter" when he wrote "argument".

Answer (score 8, accepted):

That is because the `make` subroutine is one of those rare cases in Rakudo where it actually tries to access the `$/` variable from the scope it is called from.  Which is also how it is documented:

> The sub form operates on the current $/

(from [the documentation](https://docs.raku.org/routine/make#(Match)_method_make))

Comment: Right, I'll have to link that description from the other. Also, Match appears twice, which is a document generation bug I'll have to fix...

Comment: The sub form of `make` magically uses `$/` from the "calling" scope but doesn't actually use the argument passed to it? That seems to be true based on some test code I just created. What then is the purpose of requiring an argument be passed to `make`?

Comment: What you pass to `make` is what you want to have made.  It tries to bind that to the `Match` object assumed to exist in `$/` in the scope in which the `make` is called.  The "Action-Fails" example of the original question, does not have a `$/` that is a Match object: instead it finds a `Nil`, and then dies because it cannot bind anything to that.